# How to make java detect input correctly?

Tags: java

When I change the list option in the code below, java picks up my input and gives me an answer that is really weird. This is the code:

```
package tempconverter;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import static java.lang.System.out;
public class TempConverter extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        final static String[] inList = {"From Celsius", "From Fahrenheit", "From Kelvin"};
        static JFrame f = new JFrame();
        static JTextField enter = new JTextField(3);
        static JButton confirm = new JButton("Convert");
        static JList choose = new JList(inList);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        confirm.addActionListener(new TempConverter());
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.setSize(300, 60);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(enter); 
        f.add(confirm);
        f.add(choose);
        f.setVisible(true);        
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        Object choice = choose.getSelectedValue();
        double toConvert = Double.parseDouble(enter.getText());
        double inF, inK, inC;
        if (choice.equals("From Celsius")) {
            inF = toConvert * 1.8 + 32;
            inK = toConvert + 273.15;
            out.println("In degrees Fahrenheit, " + toConvert + " degrees Celsius would be " + inF + " degrees.");
            out.println("In degrees Kelvin, " + toConvert + " degrees Celsius would be " + inK + " degrees.");
        }
        if (choice.equals("From Fahrenheit")) {
            inC = toConvert - 32 / 1.8;
            inK = toConvert - 32 / 1.8 - 273.15;
            out.println("In degrees Celsius, " + toConvert + " degrees Fahrenheit would be " + inC + " degrees.");
            out.println("In degrees Kelvin, " + toConvert + " degrees Fahrenheit would be " + inK + " degrees.");
        }
        if (choice.equals("From Kelvin")) {
            inC = toConvert - 273.15;
            inF = inC + 1.8 + 32;
            out.println("In degrees Celsius, " + toConvert + " degrees Kelvin would be " + inC + " degrees.");
            out.println("In degrees Fahrenheit, " + toConvert + " degrees Kelvin would be " + inF + " degrees.");
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make java realise that I changed the list selection?
An example I tested is that I set the selection to "From Fahrenheit" and typed 32, but it gave me 14.222222222222221 degrees Celsius and -258.92777777777775 degrees Kelvin.

Comment: what is that weird thing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 2):

It should be +273.15 instead of -273.15, and typo with `*`. Change mentioned in comment

```
if (choice.equals("From Fahrenheit")) {
    inC = toConvert - 32 / 1.8;            
    inK = toConvert - 32 / 1.8 + 273.15;
    // change here ............^......

    out.println("In degrees Celsius, " + toConvert
            + " degrees Fahrenheit would be " + inC + " degrees.");
    out.println("In degrees Kelvin, " + toConvert
            + " degrees Fahrenheit would be " + inK + " degrees.");
}

if (choice.equals("From Kelvin")) {
    inC = toConvert - 273.15;
    inF = inC * 1.8 + 32;
    // .......^.... change here

    out.println("In degrees Celsius, " + toConvert
            + " degrees Kelvin would be " + inC + " degrees.");
    out.println("In degrees Fahrenheit, " + toConvert
                + " degrees Kelvin would be " + inF + " degrees.");
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't have a difference. Should I change something else?

Comment: @TessellatingPi can you explain issue ? Output seems fine to me

Comment: Sorry resolved it I didn't put brackets to indicate what goes first based on order of operations

Comment: @TessellatingPi okay. Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

- First you have wrong calculation here.

  inF = inC + 1.8 + 32;
- here is working code.

  ```
  if (choice.equals("From Kelvin")) {
  inC = toConvert - 273.15;
  inF = (inC * 1.8) + 32;
  out.println("In degrees Celsius, " + toConvert + " degrees Kelvin would be " + inC + " degrees.");
  out.println("In degrees Fahrenheit, " + toConvert + " degrees Kelvin would be " + inF + " degrees.");
      }
  ```

  if (choice.equals("From Fahrenheit")) {
  inC = toConvert - 32 / 1.8;
  inK = (toConvert - 32 / 1.8) + 273.15;
  out.println("In degrees Celsius, " + toConvert + " degrees Fahrenheit would be " + inC + " degrees.");
  out.println("In degrees Kelvin, " + toConvert + " degrees Fahrenheit would be " + inK + " degrees.");
      }